# What is the maximum number of glyphs that a font of a TTY console can have?

Tags: tty, console

I want to my TTY console can show all Unicode UTF-8 characters.

First, I checked my locale to verify if it was set to UTF-8 mode:

```
>> Locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

And the locale settings are correct, with UTF-8 encoding.

Then I  used the `showconsolefont` command to see all glyphs for my font:

[image]

Initially, I suspected that the issue might be related to the font I was using. To troubleshoot, I attempted to change the font to several available options located in `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts`. However, I discovered that all the fonts I tried had either 256 or 512 glyphs.

So, my question is, what is the maximum number of glyphs that a font of a TTY console can have? And why?

Comment: @muru Yes, it answers my question. So, the short answer is: The terminal is supporting up to 512 glyphs.